# Qt 4.7.4 QPropertyAnimation not working 

Tags: c++, qt, animation, qwidget

I'm trying to have animation on a button click event. But somehow the animation is not working. I have referred the Qt reference docs, but could not find the root cause which is causing the issue

Below is sample code :

```
void MainWindow::AnimationClick()
{
    // define toolbar y movement positions for animation
    TOOLBAR_Y_SHOWN = 0;
    TOOLBAR_Y_HIDDEN = -m_AnimatedWidget->height();
    m_AnimatedWidget = new AnimatedWidget(this);

    QPropertyAnimation *m_ani = new QPropertyAnimation(m_AnimatedWidget, "pos", this);

    m_ani->setDuration(500);

    m_ani->setEndValue(QPoint(m_AnimatedWidget->pos().x(), TOOLBAR_Y_HIDDEN));
    m_ani->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::InBack);

    m_ani->start();
}
```

With the above implementation nothing is happening on the click event.
Any suggestions , Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I was not allowing the m_AnimatedWidget to show upon the screen.
Below is the edited snippet.

```
void MainWindow::AnimationClick()
{
    // define toolbar y movement positions for animation
    TOOLBAR_Y_SHOWN = 0;
    m_AnimatedWidget = new AnimatedWidget(this);
    TOOLBAR_Y_HIDDEN = -m_AnimatedWidget->height();


    QPropertyAnimation *m_ani = new QPropertyAnimation(m_AnimatedWidget, "pos", this);

    m_ani->setDuration(5000);

    m_ani->setEndValue(QPoint(m_AnimatedWidget->pos().x(), TOOLBAR_Y_HIDDEN));
    m_ani->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::InBack);

    m_ani->start();
    m_AnimatedWidget->show();
}
```

Comment: If this is the solution you choose, mark this answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

This looks wrong:

```
TOOLBAR_Y_HIDDEN = -m_AnimatedWidget->height();
m_AnimatedWidget = new AnimatedWidget(this);
```

First you access `m_AnimatedWidget` *then* you allocate it?

When you get a crash, such as segmentation fault, always run your program in a debugger. It would have helped you find this error quite easy as it would have stopped on the line of the error.

Comment: It was very dumb of me about allocation. Though I was running the program in debugger, it even didn't throw any error ! I have corrected the code but still the problem persists. No animation

Answer (score 0):

`m_ani->setDuration(500);`

`setDuration()` argument is expressed in milliseconds. You should probably put more than half a second when you are testing.